# What kind of type I define an argument that is of determinate class and implements determinate interface?

Tags: java

What type define an argument to make sure this is of determinate class and implements determinate interface? I'm  using  <T extends MyBaseClass & MyInterface> for argument type in method definition but my argument not extends MyBaseClass, IS of MyBaseClass type.
I want to make sure that the argument that I recive are of MyBaseClass type and implements MyInterface

Comment: I would advise against trying to determine what you have. One of the great advantages of having an interface or an abstract base class is that you don't need to know the specifics of what class you have. You just know you can call the methods specified in the interface and it will work for you, because you trust that they fulfill the contract specified by the interface. If you need to know exactly what class was passed in, you probably did something wrong with your design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are asking if you can do something like this --

```
public <T extends YourBaseClass, YourInterface> void foo(T bar) {
```

The answer is yes, you can. If you try passing an argument into this method thats YourBaseClass, but does not implement YourInterface, then the code will not compile.

Comment: @Carlos Correa -- You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You either require the argument to be of a certain concrete type (and this means its subclasses are allowed too) or to implement a certain interface.

With generics you can force an argument to be parameterized with one or more types, such as subtypes are disallowed, but as far I can see it's not pertinent to your question.

You can however, use `instanceof` in the body as well as doing comparison with `arg.getClass()`.